# Move object twoards its rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]
Look into picures its z-axis not ahead so instead on using forward i am using this line of code to translate my object on keys

robotObj.transform.position += Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * -1;

An this line of code to rotate it.

```
robotObj.transform.Rotate(0f, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, 0f);
```

but the problem is object is not moving towards it direction

Comment: Am I understanding correctly: You want to move your robotObj independent of the direction it's pointing to?

Comment: absolutely opposite to your understanding

Comment: is it moving at all?

Comment: Put a empty gameobject as parent of your robotObj and use the script to move the empty gameobject. But make sure the z-axis is facing the x-axis of the robotObj!

Comment: @Desu perfectly helpful. convert it to answer so i accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an empty gameobject as parent of your robotObj and use the script you made to move the empty gameobject. 
But make sure the z-axis is facing the x-axis of the robotObj!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move your object according to its looking direction (for you it is the red axis), then I would suggest you rotate your object first and then use `transform.right` as movement direction, like

`transform.position += transform.right* Time.DeltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Vertical")`

Note: `transform.right` take the object's local blue axis and projects it into world space (ref: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-right.html)

Note 2: Edited to use `transform.right` although I would suggest putting your GameObject into another, empty GameObject to achieve the blue axis pointing forward, so you can use `transform.forward`, as it is more intuitive.

Comment: my object forward is not correct i am moving forward through setting right

Comment: nothing happend
 robotObj.transform.Rotate(0f, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, 0f);
        robotObj.transform.position += Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * -1;

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're using the wrong overload of Rotate. Try to use `public void Rotate(Vector3 eulerAngles, Space relativeTo = Space.Self)`. You're currently using `public void Rotate(float xAngle, float yAngle, float zAngle, Space relativeTo = Space.Self)`  if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: well, then please flesh out your question a bit. it is really hard to get an idea of what the problem might be from just 2 lines of code

Comment: only written two line so far

Comment: and these two lines are in `Update`? What about your scene setup? It's like a guessing game

Comment: updated my question and the lines in update function